# yum install gcc fails with invalid linux.dropbox.com/fedora directory

Tags: linux, centos-6

I am relatively new to Linux administration. I have installed Centos 6.5 (under VirtualBox on a Win7pro system). When I try to install gcc to the system using yum, I get the following results:

```
[root@localhost etc]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Cleaning repos: Dropbox base extras updates
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
[root@localhost etc]# yum install gcc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.tummy.com
 * extras: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.freedomvoice.com
http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Dropbox. Please verify its path and try again
```

It appears that the linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6 subdirectory does not exist.
Does anyone have any hints/answers for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had above issue and using this blog (http://notepad2.blogspot.de/2013/08/install-dropbox-on-centos-linux.html) successfully sorted out using following command.

```
# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/dropbox.repo
```

Old repository:

```
[Dropbox]
name=Dropbox Repository
baseurl=http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/$releasever/
gpgkey=https://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/rpm-public-key.asc
```

Further I changed my current repository from above to below, that's it.

New repository

```
[Dropbox]  
name=Dropbox Repository
#baseurl=http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/$releasever/
baseurl=http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/19/  
gpgkey=http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/rpm-public-key.asc
```

Answer (score 0):

check out

http://notepad2.blogspot.de/2013/08/install-dropbox-on-centos-linux.html

One should change the $releasever parameter in either /etc/yum.repos.d/dropbox.repo or /etc/yum.conf to '19'

Hth,

Alex